# select statement ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT tab1.column1 FROM DB2.Schema.table1 tab1;
```

I try to execute this above query from Database 1. The table1 exist in DB2 database. It showing following error.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: You can only have schema and tablename for an identifier. You can't have the "database" as part of the identifier.

Answer (score 2):

No need to mention database name in your `select` statment. See below:

```
SELECT tab1.column1 FROM Schema.table1 tab1;
```

DB Link Usage:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK sales.hq.acme.com
   CONNECT TO scott IDENTIFIED BY tiger
   USING 'sales';
```

Once this database link is created, you can query tables in the schema SCOTT on the remote database in this manner:

```
SELECT *
   FROM emp@sales.hq.acme.com;
```

You can also use DML statements to modify data on the remote database:

```
INSERT INTO accounts@sales.hq.acme.com(acc_no, acc_name, balance)
   VALUES (5001, 'BOWER', 2000);

UPDATE accounts@sales.hq.acme.com
   SET balance = balance + 500;

DELETE FROM accounts@sales.hq.acme.com
   WHERE acc_name = 'BOWER';
```

You can also access tables owned by other users on the same database. This statement assumes SCOTT has access to ADAM's DEPT table:

```
SELECT *
   FROM adams.dept@sales.hq.acme.com;
```

The previous statement connects to the user SCOTT on the remote database and then queries ADAM's DEPT table.

```
Note: Dblinks are used using '@' symbol.
```

Comment: Yes, but I have one more database which contains same schema and same table name . then how can I differentiate these two tables.

Comment: in one database you can query for the same database only.
For other database you need to use DB link or some other mechanism ..

So in that situation also you no need to select your DB name while selecting from tables ..

Comment: And you think all databases are on same server. It should not be the case i guess. So in other case you need to create a DB link and connect to one database and query the other one

Comment: Hi XIng, all databases in same server.

Comment: Hi Pratik, If table1 in DB1 , table1 in DB2 and Table2 in DB3. Here DB1 and DB2 database table names and schema are same. Now I am going to executing this query from DB3 database. SELECT nque.col1,upush.col2 ,upush.col3
FROM NOTIFY.tab1 nque 
INNER JOIN
mobile_app.tab2 upush
ON upush.col1=nque.col1

Comment: But before executing the above query you would had somewhere defined your database coonection..i guess JDBC coonection. So you can check which DB its connected and you are querying.

Comment: Hi Pratik, If table1 in DB1 , table1 in DB2 and Table2 in DB3. Here DB1 and DB2 database table names and schema are same. Now I am going to executing this query from DB3 database. SELECT nque.col1,upush.col2 ,upush.col3
FROM NOTIFY.tab1 nque 
INNER JOIN
mobile_app.tab2 upush
ON upush.col1=nque.col1 In this scenario while I am selecting Notify.tb1 has in DB2 also. I have a doubt how this query differentiate DB1 and DB2 tables

Comment: Hi XING please look at above scenario which is the actual one

Comment: "Now I am going to executing this query from DB3 database."...your statement made itself clear..Your query will be execute in DB3 and it has nothing to do anything with DB2 or DB1..Incase you want to use DB1 or DB2..you need to create a DBLINK in Db3 to DB1 or DB2 and then in your query you can use it.

Comment: what is DBLINK how can I use it

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin003.htm.. You can google as well

Comment: Thank you XING ! can you please give some example by using above query

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix the db. Just make sure you are in the right schema using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = schemaname;
```